# How to restrict access to view node revisions with Organic Groups

Tags: 7, organic-groups

Does organic groups restrict access to node revisions as well as the nodes themselves?

I have a node page with a view of the revisions output in a block in the sidebar. OG restricts access to the node itself if the user doesn't belong to that node's group however they can see the revisions in the block.

I have tried creating my own OG permission but the organic groups permissions aren't usable in the view restriction. Not sure what else to try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than worrying about access to the revisions themselves, you might be able to add relationship to the node itself and then a filter to check it the node is accessible.

I imagine there's a better way to do it, but this might work in the mean time.